# How to display global variable in twig?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.1, twig-extension

Controller

```
$count_em =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:St_Jude_Email');
    $count_dql = $count_em->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('count(c.flag)')
            ->where('c.flag = 0');
    $flag_count = $count_dql->getQuery();
    $count = $flag_count->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $count;
```

Config.yml

```
 Twig:
  globals:  
    count: '@AppBundle\Controller\countMail'
```

How to display count which is global in twig?? 
I'm sorry, I'm new to the symfony and have no idea how to display 'count' in twig.
I tried doing {{ count }} , but got error 'An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Controller\countMail could not be converted to string").'

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return it to Template - return it as an array.

```
return ['count' => $count];
```

In other cases, if you need use globally, you need to use twig extension, [look this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).

Comment: that's not global var for twig

Answer (score 0):

@AppBundle\Controller\countMail - that's a service reference.
In your case you need to create a symfony service - https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
Then reference that service as a global twig var.
Then in your template you an reference any public method from the service
e.g {{ count.methodThat ReturnsSomeValue }}

with this approach you don't need to pass anything to twig renderer in each controller action

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service e.g. `MailService`, which holds e.g. a `countAllMail()` method. In this method you can do your DB stuff. After that you can do the following:

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_global_mail_service: '@AppBundle\Service\MailService'
```

And in your **twig template** you can use your service like this

```
{{ my_global_mail_service.countAllMail() }}
```